# How to find the cardinality of a single column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the cardinality of a column and then draw a bar plot.

This is what I have so far, however, this gives all the columns, not just the one column want to find the cardinality of.

```
df.apply(pd.Series.nunique)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `df.nunique()` to see cardinality of all columns, no need to use `apply` here. If you want, select the column you care about with `df[col_name].nunique()`.

Pandas also has some useful wrappers for quick plotting (using matplotlib under the hood), so you can plot bar plots with `df.plot.bar()`, or `df[col_name].plot.bar()` if you only care about a single column.